# Transforming Y-label to perform Multi-Label Classification

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, multilabel-classification, data-preprocessing

I am trying to implement Multi Label Classification on [Australian Skill Classification dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ruchi798/australian-skills-classification?select=Core_competencies.csv) where I have to predict multiple job titles that fits the profile out of 600 titles for a single entity.

The issue is I am not able to convert "ANZSCO_Title" in a way that I can apply Multi-Label Classification on it.

Please suggest a solution.

I tried using LabelBinarizer directly on it but that was giving me 598 zeroes and 1 one per row.

I need a y-label with these 600 titles in seperate columns being marked 1 or 0 based on if it fits the score or not.

For reference currently "ANZSCO_Title" looks like this: [Dataset Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzVLm.png)

But I want all the titles to be seperate columns so that I can apply MultiLabelBinarizer on it.